# How can I find the screen/desktop size in Qt, so I can display a desktop notification?

Tags: qt

I want to code a notification window at the bottom right corner of the desktop, so it works like Skype notifications when someone comes online. Can someone help me get the screen size of the desktop, so I can place my notification window at the bottom right corner using my Qt Application?

Comment: If you're coding notifications, you're probably better off using the OS's native notification system, which Qt provides an API for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425750/1450294

Answer (score 78):

You can use the [QDesktopWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdesktopwidget.html)

```
 auto const rec = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
 auto const height = rec.height();
 auto const width = rec.width();
```

Comment: Be careful—it's likely better to use the _available_ geometry: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry

Comment: I think you might be interested in the    QDesktopWidget::size() method instead:  for me that will return the size of two monitors stacked together as they are configured in display settings. Calling  'screenGeometry' only gives the dimensions of one monitor.

Comment: As written in the doc, QDesktopWidget class is marked as obsolete, and will probably be deprecated in next major release, so it's now better to use QScreen class, even if this one is less convenient

Comment: screenGeomoetry() is now labelled as obsoluite. The preferred method would now be:
QGuiApplication::screens()[0]->size().width()

Comment: `QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry()` is deprecated, use `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->size()` instead.

Answer (score 57):

[QScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) class (since Qt 5.0) provide information about size of screen (logical and physical), orientation and signals for changes.

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QRect  screenGeometry = screen->geometry();
int height = screenGeometry.height();
int width = screenGeometry.width();
```

upd:

- for multiscreen configuration please use `QList <QScreen*> screens = QGuiApplication::screens();`
- for orientation (including multiscreen) please use `screen->orientation()` and (since Qt 5.2)`screen->nativeOrientation()`

Comment: Can this approach also be implied for conditional loading of `QML` pages (for instance, different `QML` pages for different screen resolutions/orientation) in both Android and Linux (Desktop/Embedded)?

Comment: this option is preferred as QApplication::desktop() is made obsolete (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html)

Comment: What to do when the current screen is not the primary one? I have the window appear on a portrait mode display, but it seems primaryScreen refers to the main display, which is landscape.

Comment: @KernelPanic It can be used for conditional loading QML/rendering. For dynamic hardware configuration please check  `primaryScreenChanged / screenAdded / screenRemoved` from QGuiApplication(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html)

Comment: @oarfish Yes, primaryScreen - from OS point of view(and not from app). In multi-monitor configuration you need to obtain a list of screens `QList <QScreen*> screens = QGuiApplication::screens()`.  `QScreen` include property `availableGeometry` and `availableVirtualGeometry` - knowing a position of `QWindow`(signals`xChanged/yChanged`) you may find exact screen of application and use correct orientation.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't stated which platform you're developing for, but some platforms have API for showing notifications. It's best to use those, when available, because the bottom right if the screen may not be appropriate. You can fall back on krammer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18975846/1450294).

In GNOME, for example, the user can make notifications appear on a particular screen, or elect to not show them at all, until they click on a system tray icon. The [`libnotify`](https://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/) API gives the developer access to this feature.

Speaking of system trays, you may want to consider using a [`QSystemTrayIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html) instead. It would make UI a bit different, but has a platform-independent Qt API, which works for GNOME, KDE, MacOS, Windows and probably other platforms. It also has a [`showMessage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage) method for showing messages in a manner native for the platform, such as in a balloon with a cute popping sound for some versions of Windows.

Comment: @SanathReddy: I haven't tried it, but maybe this will do what you want: https://github.com/KDE/snorenotify