# After SDL_Quit(), return interrupt csignal control back to Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, sdl

I'm working on a program that only needs to use SDL to get screen resolutions when needed. I'd like to start the SDL init, get what I need, then close it. But I'm having trouble because when I start the SDL is takes over the single interrupt handle, I can't even set it to SIG_IGN...

I have a `main` method that creates a `QApplication` and a `mainWidget`.

While running, a function in the `mainWidget` starts an SDL instance using the following code:

```
bool MainWidget::getSomeSdlInformation()
{
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "software");
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    SDL_Init(0);
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "SDL_Init failed: " << QString::fromUtf8(SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return false;
    }
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

   // Get the needed video information

   // Quit SDL
   SDL_Quit();
   return true;
}
```

After I "Quit SDL" I'd like to return the csignal interrupt back to QT, such that when a user presses control-c the program closes gracefully.

I'm having some trouble figuring our how to return control of the handle back to QT.

Here is an a crash log from preforming the control-c operation on my existing implementation:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fffffffd2f0) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66

66  ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
```

(gdb) bt

```
#0  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fffffffd2f0) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66

#1  0x00007ffff48070da in XrmQGetResource () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6

#2  0x00007ffff47e4a42 in XGetDefault () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6

#3  0x00007ffff43ab0d0 in _XcursorGetDisplayInfo () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1

#4  0x00007ffff43ab1a9 in XcursorGetDefaultSize () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1

#5  0x00007ffff43ad435 in XcursorLibraryLoadCursor () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1

#6  0x00007ffff706ed5c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#7  0x00007ffff706f485 in QCursor::handle() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#8  0x00007ffff707b364 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#9  0x00007ffff7080398 in QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned long, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#10 0x00007ffff703231d in QWidget::create(unsigned long, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#11 0x00007ffff703a86a in QWidget::setVisible(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

#12 0x0000000000421270 in show (this=0x7fffffffda60) at /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:497

#13 main (argc=1, argv=) at /home/jeff/Dev/openmw/apps/launcher/main.cpp:55
```

Comment: Can you use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975734/how-do-i-get-the-screen-size-of-desktop-where-i-am-running-my-qt-application to get the screen resolution or does it have to be SDL?

Comment: Try saving the signal handler before entering SDL, then restore it on exit (twice - you have two returns)