# QDesktopWidget availableGeometry() in Qt not working correctly, need to scroll vertically to view complete image

Tags: c++, image, qt, scroll, screen

I have a background image that I would like to display in a `QGraphicsView` in Qt 5.7. I would like the size of the window to be such that it covers my entire screen exactly, without the need to scroll. So, I would like to ensure it leaves space for the taskbar in Windows and the top and left panels in Ubuntu (I am using Ubuntu 14.04).

I found from the Qt documentation that [QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry) is the function to use for this purpose. This has been reiterated in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893751/5987698) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975734/how-can-i-find-the-screen-desktop-size-in-qt-so-i-can-display-a-desktop-notific#comment56593091_18975846).

However, when I try to use this, I observe that a small part of the image is cut off, if I set the scroll bar policy to `Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff`, and if not, I need to scroll slightly vertically.

Here's a small sample code:

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QImage>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
    view->setScene(scene);
    QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
    int screenHeight = rec.height();
    int screenWidth = rec.width();
    QImage *back = new QImage("image.jpg");
    QImage *background = new QImage(back->scaled(screenWidth,screenHeight,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation));
    QBrush *brush = new QBrush(*background);
    view->setBackgroundBrush(*brush);
 //   view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
 //   view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view->setFixedSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);
    view->setSceneRect(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My screen resolution is 1366x768 pixels, so I have used an image of that size, and scaled it using the `QImage::scaled()` function before displaying.

For example, if the input is:
[image: input image]
Image Attribution : [Mirela1234](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Mirela1234), [1366x768-Natural-desktop-wallpaper](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1366x768-Natural-desktop-wallpaper.jpg), [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode)

When I run the above code, I get:
[image: result]
(I have cropped the top and left panels from the screen).

Why is this happening? Does `availableGeometry()` not account for, say, the title bar? How can I correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

availableGeometry() works perfectly correct :)

The problem is that you are not taking into the account frame size. You resizing image to maximum availableGeometry, but frame of window takes some place too. In the end you have image bigger, then free space on widget. That's why you got scrollbar.

What you can do is for example:

```
// 2 - because frame border is on the bottom and on the top.
QImage *background = new QImage(back->scaledToHeight(rec.height() - view->frameWidth() * 2));
```

That will works.